# Make a wordpress page with maps responsive

Tags: css, wordpress

I have built a page with interactive world maps plugin at http://www.parentcenterhub.org/find-your-center/

All other pages of my site are responsive except this one. What CSS should I add and in which file so that this page is also responsive on all devices (Android,iPhone, tablets, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if twentythirteen is responsive by default, but that shouldn't be a problem. You should add [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) in your css file, specifying specific widths where your page 'breaks', and add css specific for that width.

For instance for mobile you'd have

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
/* css goes here*/
}
```

And for every major element you'd specify how it behaves when the width of your screen is less than 767px.

There are lots of tutorials on line, so check them out.